# Jquery animate object using '+=px' stop at a certain px

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

i want to animate object from left to right, i am using `animate` jquery, i am using this to animate from left to right, but not a straight line, i want to movie it on a zigzag pattern, this is my code:

```
function bird1(){
        $(".bird1").delay(3).animate({left:'+=100',bottom:'+=20'},2222,"linear");
        $(".bird1").animate({left:'+=100',bottom:'-=20'},2222,"linear",bird1);
    }
    bird1();
```

it will move but i will not stop, i want is to stop the bird if it reach the 1060px left. Help please. Or i can use an another method

Thanks

Comment: Did any of the answers below answer your question? If so, will you please mark the most helpful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution is to simply check `left` value in the begining of the `bird1` function. Check the demonstration:

```js
function bird1() {
    
    if (parseInt($('.bird1').css('left')) > 300) {
        return;
    }
    
    $(".bird1").delay(3).animate({left: '+=100', bottom: '+=20' }, 2222, "linear");
    $(".bird1").animate({left: '+=100',bottom: '-=20'}, 2222, "linear", bird1);
}

bird1();
```

```css
.bird1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bird1">
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-set/24/Twitter-32.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some method to check the left offset in your callback and there is ofcourse the [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method to do this.

In your example, this should do the trick, changing 200 with any number suitable for what you're doing.

```
function bird1(){
    $(".bird1").delay(3).animate({left:'+=100',bottom:'+=20'},2222,"linear");
    $(".bird1").animate({left:'+=100',bottom:'-=20'},2222,"linear",
        function(){
            var offset = $('.bird1').offset()
            if (offset.left < 200) bird1();
    });
}
```

Note: you may use offset.left or offset.top and act accordingly - offset here being

```js
    function bird1() {
      $(".bird1").delay(3).animate({
        left: '+=100',
        bottom: '+=20'
      }, 2222, "linear");
      $(".bird1").animate({
          left: '+=100',
          bottom: '-=20'
        }, 2222, "linear",
        function() {
          var offset = $('.bird1').offset()
          if (offset.left < 200) bird1();
        });
    }

    $('#fly').on('click', function() {
      bird1();
    });
```

```css
.bird1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fafafa;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bird1">I'm flying</div>
<button id="fly">flap</button>
```

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjytnp11/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    var maxLeft = 1060;
    var zagIncLeft = 100;
    var zagIncTop = 20;
    var zagTopSwitch = '+';
    var bird = $('#bird');
    setInterval(function() {
        if (parseInt(bird.css('left')) < maxLeft) {
            bird.animate({
                left: '+=' + zagIncLeft,
                top: zagTopSwitch + '=' + zagIncTop
            }, 999, "linear");
            if (zagTopSwitch == '+') {
                zagTopSwitch = '-';
            } else {
                zagTopSwitch = '+';
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#bird {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bird"></div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwqdosv0/